# sails.js beforeCreate method receives only the model properties on which required is set to true

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

This is a model in sails.js.

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: "string"
        },
        email: {
            type: "email",
            required: true
        },
        password: {
            type: "string"
        }
    },

    beforeCreate: function(values, next) {
        console.log(values); //logs {email:"mail@someplace.com"}
        console.log(values.email);    // logs the email id sent via post
        console.log(values.password);    // logs undefined is required is set to false, If required is set to true, password will log properly.
        next();
    }
};
```

I am planning to perform some encrypting of the password in the beforeCreate function, Of course I will be requiring the password and can continue with it right now but how to manage this for optional values just in case the need arises?

Comment: Did you add model with rest api or from a controller ? Are you sending all fields or just email from your front ?

Comment: Have you try to used the beforeValidate method instead ? To see if it's different

Comment: @jaumard,I am building a REST API without views, this model is bound to a route named /auth/signup. I am doing a POST via advanced rest console chrome app, and yes, I am posting all the fields.

Comment: Ok, I found the issue, there is some issue in my controller where i do 'Users.findOrCreate'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason for the above issue,
In my controller, I was doing a create record but the record I was creating contained only one field, i.e the `email` see below:

```
Users.create({email:req.body.email}).exec(function(err, user){
   // user created
});
```

The model is directly mapped with the object being inserted into the database, So internally sails removes/ignores the fields which are not present.
To not remove these empty fields, you might have to set `schema:true` in your model.